# Problem in position absolute, fixed in parent tag

Tags: css

I want to move the discount label from right to left.
But the label comes out of its parent and sticks to the inflatable wall

[image]

```css
  .lable-off{
position : absolute;
left : 0px
top : 0px
  }
```

Comment: do you have position: relative on parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you container does not have `position: relative`. So try to set `position: relative` for container :

An example:

```css
.foo {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="foo">
    <span class="bar">1</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my code in container and it's similar to what you wrote but it doesn't work

Comment: @MohammadrezaGolshahi see it carefully. `position: relative` should be in container